# What directory should Ubuntu touch apps write to

Tags: application-development, configuration, phone

What directory should Ubuntu touch apps write to. Is there a Qt or QML method for getting this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu touch apps write to ~/.local/share/applicationName, where applicationName is the name you defined in MainView and manifest.json.in

You can access data in that directory via a c++ addon. You find a great example in the code from Podbird: https://launchpad.net/podbird Focus on the QStandardPaths class.

However, most times it is not necessary to know the path. You can store and read settings for example via Local Storge: https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04.3/QtQuick.qtquick-localstorage-example/